# flutter safety use notifyListeners

Tags: flutter, flutter-change-notifier

```
A Model was used after being disposed.
```

such like:

```
Model(){
fetchData();
}
void fetchData() async{
 final r = await requset();
//...do something
notifyListeners();
}
```

when i use notifyListeners(),but the model had disposed. how to safety use notifyListeners()?

Comment: call fetchData only if your widget is mounted. Eg: `if(mounted) fetchData();`

Comment: i used provider.  fetchData() callback, but the page dispose .

Comment: You cannot call the function once your page has been disposed. <- (your widget is not present in the widget tree anymore)